# Internet explorer not responding after auto startup

Tags: internet-explorer-9

sorry this isn't exactly programming but I have a problem.

I have set a simple task using task scheduler in windows to start internet explorer when the computer starts, and it will open internet explorer then it will go into "Not Responding"

Here is a bit more information on the setup:

14 machines
All set to login to the "Student" account automatically
When internet explorer is started using task scheduler it crashes on every machine on startup then after shutting IE down it will crash every now and again.

Now even on one of the machines that I have turned off the auto start on it's still responding when it is started manually.

It's IE 9 we are using.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First I checked the windows error logs, next I found that it was IEFRAME.dll that was causing the issues.

Updated the browser and it fixed it. In my case I didn't want to update it because we need the old version, so I updated it and will downgrade if the software we use is not compatible.

Not an amazing answer, but it works.